# C#: Retrieving log messages from Eventlogs

Tags: c#, system.diagnostics

I am new to using the Log class in c#. I have tried reading the official documentation but I still can't understand where the logs are being stored.

I have tried EventLog.GetEventLogs() but it seems to be not returning me the messages that I logged.

I also tried browsing through the default temporary log folder(C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp) but I could not find anything related to my log.

I have this code in my program to log messages and events:

```
WriteEntry(msgString, type, Mode);
```

And here is the code I am using to try and retrieve the logs:

```
 var d = EventLog.GetEventLogs();
 foreach (EventLog l in d)
 {
   foreach (EventLogEntry entry in l.Entries)
   {
      // process
      Console.WriteLine(">>" + entry.Message);
   }
 }
```

To wrap it up, How do you retrieve the logs?

Comment: There's no way we can answer this without more info.  What you've described should work.

Comment: Retrieve them programmatically or manually? Manually: just use the Event Viewer app in Windows. Programmatically - do what you're doing, and investigate whether they were written in the first place instead.

Comment: yes, the example works but the main question here is how do you do the opposite and retrieve the whole log message? @rory.ap

Comment: retrieve it programmatically. @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ

Comment: Well `GetEventLogs` returns a collection of logs. You just need to iterate through them.

Comment: Post the *actual* code you used to read log events. Event Log works. It doesn't store anything it temporary folders. It isn't broken. What you posted doesn't read events, just the list of available logs

Comment: I have posted the code that I have been trying to work on. @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: Don't read all logs, just find the one you want and read the events. Which log are you looking for? Have you checked the `EventLog(logName)` constructor? What is your log's name? What is your actual problem?

Comment: PS. You don't know nor should you care where the logs are stored. These are neither text nor XML files. You provide the *name* and the OS retrieves the entries. Were you trying to provide the path instead of the log name perhaps?

Comment: it uses this line : "_directory = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Properties.Resources.ProcedureManagerLogs);"  @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: The location is irrelevant. How did you name your log? You write or read a log using its name, not its location

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure. I could not find the **EventLog(logName) ** that you mentioned in the code. @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: If you don't know how the event log is called, how do you expect to read from it? Can you find it in Event Viewer?